What is the term for letter strings with set sound patterns in a particular language?
As I am going through my old notes, I can't seem to find a term that I am trying to call to mind. For example, the letter string "sh" is usually realized as [ʃ], ph as [f], ng as [ŋ], "ay" as [eɪ], the same way "sch" is pronounced as [ʃ] in German and "in" as [ɛ̃] in French. What are these letter strings called? They are not morphemes, as morphemes are morphologically defined and not phonologically based. A morpheme may contain more than one of the kind of "letter string" at issue. They don't seem to be graphemes either.

phonemes? Not sure what you mean by strings...

Do you mean digraphs, trigraphs (...)?

Grapheme, already mentioned in your question, appears to be correct answer. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grapheme: "(linguistics) In alphabetic writing, the shortest group of letters composing a phoneme."

@Arfrever that’s only one view of graphemes, and it is not unproblematic; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme.

@Arfrever, I think you should write an answer. The other answers don't include a string of length 1 which the asker might be interested in. And your answer should contain the caveat that Keelan gave, that only some people extend the word "grapheme" to strings longer than 1.

When it's two graphemes together, it's a digraph, three is a trigraph, and so on.
So, while I've never actually heard this word before, I think generalizing to n-graphs would be easily enough understood. (Compare "n-grams" for the generalization of bigrams, trigrams, etc in NLP.)
The "proper" Greek formation would be polygraphs, but that already means something else, and the "poly-" prefix isn't used especially often in linguistics. Multigraphs would be a bit better, but that also already means something else. Best to stick with n-graphs, in my opinion.

given the relatively few number of letters in an n-graph (German tsch seems about as extreme as they get), oligograph could potentially also work, although I agree that n-graph is probably more reasonable

The extreme I know is a heptagraph; schtsch in the German transcription of Russian  Щ

The terms “digraph” and “trigraph” are widely used for strings of length 2 or 3.
According to this unsourced Wikipedia article, the generalized term is “multigraph” or “pleograph”.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph_(orthography). The longest example on that page is ⟨schtsch⟩ which is used for transliterating the Ukrainian letter ⟨щ⟩ into German. When I read the talk page for that Wikipedia article, I can’t tell if “pleograph” is something coined by a Wikipedia editor.
To identify sources, I tried querying Google Scholar. I added the word “orthography” to my queries because I saw that some of these terms are also used as jargon outside of linguistics. Here are my results:

“digraph multigraph orthography”. 332 results. This one follows that usage: Orthography development
"digraph pleograph orthography”. 0 results.
“digraph polygraph orthography”. 141 results. This one follows that usage: St. lawrence island eskimo phonology and orthography
“digraph n-graph orthography”. 48 results. This is one that follows that usage Morphemes, syllables, and graphemes in written word production

You can’t draw a lot of conclusions from the counts because Googleology is bad science. I can’t conclude how widespread these usages are, but I can conclude that someone has used the words “multigraph”, “polygraph”, and “n-graph” for these.
I haven’t found any usage of the word “pleograph” in this sense yet, but I think the adjective “pleographic” may mean a spelling system which can use sequences of letters for a sound:

Slavic Alphabets in Contact A Danylenko - 2017 - JSTOR … While
identifying polyvalent (primitive), combinatory, ‘pleographic’ and
diacritic types of spelling the author investigates the historical
interdependence of typesetting in Fraktur


Symbolika a rěcywěda: pismo a pšawopis w słowjańskich rěcach R Marti -
LĚTOPIS. Zeitschrift für sorbische Sprache, Geschichte …, 2008 -
ceeol.com Written language is generally regarded as little more than a
… is often more important than linguistic considerations. This is …
and letter (monographic, pleographic, and combinatory writing)

